# Redirect all of the traffic to https://www. Currently I have two versions http://www and https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have a brand new site, initially, it was http:// then I redirected the site to http://www it worked liked a charm, but since I installed the SSL I have two versions of website http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com.
I have tried several commands in .htaccess but still I have two versions can someone please help me with this, below is the code I am using in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

First www and after https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Clear your cache before testing or try with another browser

Comment: Thanks @croises. I have cleared cache in browser, varnish and restarted the apache as well but still it goes to http://www

Comment: The problem is not in this htaccess. Certainly in the server configuration

Comment: Or do you use a non-standard SSL version?

Comment: any suggestions how can i change the server configuration, both https and now https versions are working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No, because you redirect without www to https and after again with www = 2 x 301 redirections. If you redirect first without www to https//www, no need to redirect after to https. And it's the same in the question...

Comment: Ooops, I just noticed that it is the same as in the question. My bad :\